# CSS :first-letter not working

Tags: html, css

Need to show first letter bigger than other letters.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mc165upk/1/

But background should be shown with line height.

css:

```
.main-heading p {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: inline;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    line-height: 91px;
    background: #faf98e;
    font-size:72px;
}
.t1-result-topheading p:first-letter { font-size: 108px; }
```

Comment: Pseudo Classes (such as that `first-letter`) should have double colons ("`::`").  It should be like this:  `::first-letter { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

The :first-letter as defined in the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter only applies to a block level element.
So if you want to use ::first-letter selector you have to make the element `display:inline-block;`.

Also there was error in your css `.t1-result-topheading p:first-letter { font-size: 108px; }` was not available in your html code , so fixed that as well.

> Working snippet:

```css
.main-heading p {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  line-height: 91px;
  background: #faf98e;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.main-heading p::first-letter{ color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="main-heading">
  <p>How much should you pay for a video campaign?</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

> The Jquery solution if you want to use display:inline only.

```js
$('p').html(function (i, html)
{
    return html.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])/g, '<span class="First--letter">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.main-heading p {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  line-height: 91px;
  background: #faf98e;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.First--letter{ color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-heading">
  <p>How much should you pay for a video campaign?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can not use inline block here. It is not giving the extra space in between any paragraph text

Comment: are you talking about the vertical space?

Comment: If you want to use display:inlin only then you have to do this with jquery solution.. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter), `:first-letter` will only work for block-level elements. Since you explicitly set your paragraph to be `display: inline;`, `:first-letter` will not work. You can fix it by setting `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`.

There was another error in your fiddle in that `.t1-result-topheading` was not a parent class in the HTML for that paragraph, so the style wouldn't be applied anyway.

**Edit:** Since you want to maintain spaces between the lines, you can accomplish this by wrapping your text in a `span` (inline by default), applying the background color to the span, and using `:first-letter` on the paragraph (which will be block-level by default).

```css
.main-heading span {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  line-height: 91px;
  background: #faf98e;
  font-size: 72px;
}

p:first-letter {
  font-size: 108px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-heading">
  <p><span>How much should you pay for a video campaign?</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can not use inline block or  block  here. I want extra  white space in between paragraph text you can check fiddle

Comment: Updated the answer to address these requirements.

Answer (score 2):

1. The "parent" element of this: `.t1-result-topheading p:first-letter { ... }` points to a non-existing element (as what is written on your code, on your fiddle).  There is no such element as `.t1-result-topheading`, and therefore will not apply the CSS rule.
2. Use `display: inline-block` as this will let the element have a `width` and a `height`.

   As what [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) have said:

   > inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a width and a height.

---

Therefore, your code should be:

```css
.main-heading p {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    line-height: 91px;
    background: #faf98e;
    font-size:72px;
}
.main-heading p::first-letter { font-size: 108px; }
```

```html
<div class="main-heading">
<p>How much should you pay for a video campaign?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: First, what is OP?  Well, sorry if I don't know the meaning of that word, but could I know? Anyways, I'm not sure why he wants extra space between the paragraphs.  Another answer on this question (by @Karin), states that you should use `span`, instead of `p`.  [Link here ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906766/css-first-letter-not-working/43906816#43906816)

Answer (score 1):

Update css code below

```
.main-heading p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS ::first-letter Selector

```
p::first-letter {
   font-size: 200%;
   color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link for understanding the `first-letter`  [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp][1]

```
.t1-result-topheading p::first-letter { font-size: 108px; }
```